# What does the letter at the end of Patema Inverted mean?

Tags: patema-inverted

Near the end of the movie, we see the letter from Lagos. However it seems to be encoded. What does it mean?

[image: letter]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post on MyAnimeList forums](https://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1171937#SFRlu1Zqh4MTx5Wu.99), this is the message:

> From: ?AIA Sent: Tue???y,??ly 29,v???x ?:30PM To: Ma????ng list fre?ds
>   Cc: ?? com?unity Subject: We are alive. Attachments: I?mage582
>   Image6?5 Im??e661
>
> This E-mail is an appeal to all recipients.
>
> We are alive We were spared the effects of the anti-gravity
>   experiment.
>
> We have yet to fully grasp the extent of the destruction But we are
>   absolutely certain that one particular undamaged area remains; namely,
>   the area on the exact opposite side of the Earth's mantle. This is the
>   reverse side of the Earth's axis.
>
> After settling that area, we pushed forward with research into the
>   repair of gravity inversion. Now it seems a successful breakthough may
>   by just out of reach. We have placed our hopes in the networks still
>   online in each area, and are transmitting this E-mail all over the
>   Earth.
>
> To all recipients: please print as many copies of this E-mail as
>   possible. Then please distribute those copies to as many people, as
>   you can, so that they may know the truth.
>
> We are resolved to wait in here, for generations if necessary.
>
> Latitude 33.3526' N, Longitude 130.2401' E
>
> Please convey this to all peopple on Earth. We are alive.

[Here's the location on the map.](https://www.google.com/maps/place/33.3526N+130.2401E/)

Comment: maybe you should've explain a bit how did he decipher it.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it was read out loud in full at some point. I watched it some time ago. Maybe if somebody has subtitles on hand they could ctrl+f through it.

Comment: Now I am more confused. At the end of the film, are they at Latitude 33.3526' N, Longitude 130.2401' E already?

Comment: Potentially, yes. But this is the world after some stuff has gone down and everything changed. It points to an ordinary park in Japan (where the movie was created) which is supposed to be reachable by regular people (of Japan). Perhaps it has some significance to the creators. The rest is up to your imagination.